Why hasn't the Harris campaign been criticizing the Trump administration's COVID performance?
The US performed demonstrably poorly at handling COVID, and Trump was in power during the most crucial part of the pandemic, so it seems like the Harris campaign would have room to attack Trump on this issue (especially since Trump said some demonstrably silly things about Covid, e.g. this).
Why haven't they been doing it?

Blatant push question

Maybe get rid of the "demonstrably poor" line?  Just asking neutrally why Harris is not being more aggressive on the subject is enough.  However... I do think the reasons why - assuming she is indeed soft-pedaling it - won't be verifiable by public info.

@ItalianPhilosopher I give you permission to make it less pushy, if you can. I bet you can't.

@Allure Just my 2c. If this "The US performed demonstrably poorly at handling COVID" could be reworded to "The US is said by analysts (link to at least 2-3 sources) to have performed demonstrably poorly at handling COVID" then the question could avoid making a hard scientific claim, and could be more likely to be reopened / stay open. Just IMO. FYI I voted to reopen already. But citing sources could better indicate the performance evaluation is subjective rather than objective (but without sacrificing the strength of the case for the affirmative in it being poorly handled)

@stevec Honestly I've already gotten the answer I was looking for (which I wrote in a comment, but it's been deleted), so I've become less interested in this question. If you are interested in it, I'd say go ahead and edit it yourself. In my case the "sources" is that, if you sort the Worldometers table by cases or deaths per capita, the US is above the world average, by a considerable margin.

They did it sometimes, on some issues (e.g. roughly this week "Harris Seizes on Claims That Trump Sent Putin Covid Tests"), even somewhat briefly in the Harris-Trump televised debate.

Harris accused Trump of leaving the Biden administration "the worst public health epidemic in a century.” Trump claimed the U.S. made ventilators for "the entire world." [...]
Harris also hit Trump for thanking Chinese leader Xi Jinping for Covid despite China not being transparent about Covid's origins.

But nowadays that's mostly water under the bridge. OTOH Trump's health and ramblings are not. Many Americans are forward looking as you saw in the poll difference/jump from Biden to Harris.
Besides, Biden on some (other) COVID issues allegedly ended up agreeing with Trump, e.g. in 2022:

"There is no federal solution," President Joe Biden told the nation's governors last week while addressing surging COVID cases from the Omicron variant, the latest wrinkle in the coronavirus pandemic. "This gets solved at the state level."
That's exactly what then-President Donald Trump said in 2020. While campaigning for the presidency, Biden accused Trump of "not having a plan" to beat COVID, while he himself did. Now, with this apparent reversal of his campaign message, Biden seems to be channeling the position championed by his predecessor, who said in April 2020 that the federal government should be a "backstop" for whatever states chose to do to control their health emergencies.


It may be true that the US did have more corona  than other countries but to hold that against Trump you would first need to prove that  it's not an apples to orange comparison and that those countries faced identical risk factors which were only avoided because they took policies notably different than what Trump advocated .
Furthermore,  better let sleeping dogs. A lot of what the Democrats said against Trump's handling of corona in 2020 has too much potential to come back and bite them if the issue resurfaces today.  Public opinion about corona measures have changed greatly since 2020. The anti-Trump ads of October 2020  featuring children dying in hospitals and gravely intoning how cruel Trump is for wanting more of them with his insistence schools should reopen look so bad today that they have been scrubbed off the internet. (I couldn't find them when looking for a link for this answer)  Former NYS governor Andrew Cuomo who was once held up (by Democrats) as  the epitome of what  successful corona  management should be is now  a disgraced former politician. Even when it comes to corona measures. De Santis did campaign against Trump on Corona issues. He faulted him for  NOT firing Fauci. Back then Fauci was considered a hero. etc.

"you would first need to prove" Not in politics. If this were true, Trump wouldn't have been able to finish the first month of this first presidency. For the better or worse, it's only important what people believe (a bit like in a religion). And lost of people believe that Trump handled Corona badly and more people died because of it, but others, especially prospective Trump voters do not believe it. That's probably why it's not really a topic. If anything the reasons for the million people who died of Corona in the US alone will be processed over many years to come.

@NoDataDumpNoContribution nobody cares about the virus or its victims in the US, people only discuss the economic effects of it, but never once did I hear anyone bring up the "millions of people who died". Reason is very simple: only 0.36% died and the vast majority were old, frail or had major per-existing conditions. Inflation is about 100x more important to the voters than excess deaths in 2020-2021. Only countries like NZ care because their politicians use their Zero Covid 'success' as an excuse to explain failures in other policy areas. Americans have long forgotten about it.

@JonathanReez You like hyperbole right? Nobody cares about the Corona victims in the US is definitely wrong. It will come. People will certainly discuss how they missed beloved ones. Maybe it simply takes more time to process it. Or the mainstream is to want to move on. But such topics keep coming back. This question here is better than its current score.

@NoDataDumpNoContribution median Covid victim had 3-4 years left to live, so without Covid most of them would be dead by now anyway. Not to mention how many deaths happened in nursing homes where the victims had dementia, Alzheimers and other horrible conditions that made them a shadow of their former selves. And yes, people will talk about how crazy it was to panic over Covid, instead of just letting it rip and moving on.
